# Insert an list element into a document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to insert a new element into a document. And i did the following:

```
l=[78.0, 97.5, 97.5]
new_one   = {"my_list" : l}
insert_id = dbh.users.update({"p_id":'100'}, {"$push":new_one}, upsert=False, safe=True)
```

Then, when i retrieve this list, i did:

```
docs = dbh.users.find_one({"p_id": '100'})
print docs.get('my_list')
```

However, i got a nested list like the following

```
>> [[78.0, 97.5, 97.5]]
```

How could i get a list, not nested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than pushing, you just want to set.

By pushing, you are saying to add your list to a list, which is why it came out nested.

Simply replace `$push` with `$set`.

```
> l=[78.0, 97.5, 97.5]
[ 78, 97.5, 97.5 ]
> new_one   = {"my_list" : l}
> insert_id = db.users.update({"p_id":'100'}, {"$set":new_one}, upsert=true, safe=true)
> db.users.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52c3a5682420d55400369a59"), "my_list" : [ 78, 97.5, 97.5 ], "p_id" : "100" }
```